# Почему алгоритм проверки из man acl не соответствует фактическому разграничению прав

Tags: linux, debian, acl

В `man acl` в разделе алгоритм проверки сказано

```
2.   else if the effective user ID of the process matches the qualifier of any entry of type ACL_USER, then
              if the matching ACL_USER entry and the ACL_MASK entry contain the requested permissions, access is granted,
              else access is denied.
```

Как я понимаю, если есть правило для пользователя (не владельца), то, если этот пользователь обращается к файлу, то разрешенные права соответвуют этой записи, алгоритм завершается.

Создаём файл и назначаем ему права:

```
echo "echo 123" > /file1
chmod 005 /file1
setfacl -m u:test1:--- /file1
setfacl -m mask:--- /file1
chown usertest:root /file1
```

Получили

```
userc@client:~$ getfacl /file1
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: file1
# owner: usertest
# group: root
user::---
user:test1:---
group::---
mask::---
other::r-x
```

Если я правильно понимаю алгоритм, то доступ за запуск и чтение разрешен всем, кроме `usertest` и `test1`, но захожу за `test1` и запускаю файл:

```
test1@client:~$ sh /file1
123
```

т.е. он идёт дальше по алгоритму, доходит до `others` и берёт его права.
Если у файла сделать группу владельца, которая присутствует у `test1`, то права файла на запуск-чтение станут недоступны, но ведь группы проверяются на шаге 3, после правил `ACL` для пользователей!

Почему алгоритм проверки из man acl не соответствует фактическому разграничению прав? Почему правило ACL_USER игнорируется и доходит до others?

Comment: `$ sh /file1` — это не «запуск файла», а запуск программы *sh*. «запуск» — это: `$ /file1`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin проблемы это не решает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем примере если пользователь **usertest** запустил **file1**, будут действовать правила для владельца (в данном случае будет их отсутствие). Другим пользователям эти правила владельца никак не действуют. Если пользователь состоит в группе той , что у файла, И пользователь НЕ владелец файла то будут выполнятся правила группы. Дальше похожие правила: если пользователь не владелец файла И пользователь НЕ состоит в группе файла ТО будут выполнятся правила для остальных.

Comment: Так я командой `setfacl -m u:test1:--- /file1` полностью запретил по идее доступ к файлу пользователю `test1`, а по факту он его может запустить. Почему он проигнорировал 2-й шаг алгоритма то и перешел к группам, а затем к Остальным?

Comment: Попробуйте в **/etc/fstab** при монтировании добавить опцию **acl**.

Comment: да это все есть

Comment: Значит маска виновата: попробуйте `setfacl -m m::rwx file1`

Comment: Маска. Если маска отсутствует, то правила ACL_USER и ACL_GROUP игнорируются. А запись mask:--- почему-то интерпретируется как её отсутствие, что, по-моему, не логично. Ведь если я захочу всем записям ACL_USER временно запретить все права, назначить mask:--- не получится, ведь права будут браться из others. Бред имхо.

Comment: Поковырялся и определил правила. Это продвинутое управление правами работает только для пользователей, который не владелец файла. Для группы отличной от группы файла. Если ты владелец файла, то ACL не рассматривается. Если ты в группе файла, то ACL тоже не рассматривается. Если пользователь не владелец и не в группе то ACL не в теме. Маска ущемляет права только в пределах ACL. `mask:---` с неработающим ACL это баг. Попробуйте найти свежую версию. Нормальная работающая : 2.2.52

Comment: Это к разработчикам отечественной "операционной системы, которую невозможно взломать", к сожалению.